# Kernel Build Logs location

Tags: build, linux-kernel, android-kernel

Is there a location where kernel build logs are found while doing standard kernel compilation.
One way is to redirect the output to the file.

```
source <build_script> > build_log_file.txt
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Qs is where to find the kernel build logs.

Answer (score 3):

It goes into stdout and stderr. If you want it to go to a file instead you can:

```
make > <logfile> 1>&2
```

If you want the output to go into file and the screen you can

```
make 2>&1 | tee <logfile>
```